# Getting source of the websites using file_get_content

Tags: php, regex

I have a list of a couple of thousands websites. I have to iterate over them, and in each iteration - call file_get_contents of the given url, search for some information from the source using regex, and write it to another file.

Ok, the thing is - it's very, very slow. I divided the whole process into searching for about 50 urls each time I refresh the page. But:

- I'd have to refresh the page until I get to a couple of thousand
- even with only 50 urls, I get 30sec time exceeded

Is there a way to speed this up?

Comment: Parallel server processes

Comment: It would help to run the requests asynchronous using e.g. https://github.com/amphp/artax. But even than 30seconds isn't really much and sounds like a strange requirement for what you are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set_time_limit ( int $seconds ) could help you to increase the maximum execution time. 
http://php.net/manual/fr/function.set-time-limit.php

I assume you're using your script frow a browser. Maybe you should consider execution from command line, since it's better for long execution time scripts.

Comment: Get ready to get new skills ;-) http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php